# How to add Azure Scaleset to Log Analytics

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-log-analytics, azure-vm-scale-set

How do I add Azure Scale Set to Log analytics. From log analytics I am able to see the VM but unlike VMs the connect button is not enabled. What do I need to do. to enable this connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a MSDN post regarding this issue:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2018/04/09/how-to-add-the-oms-client-to-a-vm-scale-set/

As mentioned in the post, we explain how to do this for VMs but not for VMSS. You can accomplish this via PowerShell and the linked blog above describes how to achieve it.

I will add the script below for users who don't want to follow the link

```
select-azurermsubscription -subscriptionid ‘your subscription id’
$PublicSettings = @{"workspaceId" = "your oms workspace id"}
$ProtectedSettings = @{"workspaceKey" = "your big base64 oms key"}

# Get information about the scale set
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName 'VMSSRESOURCEGROUP' `
-VMScaleSetName 'VMSSNAME'

Add-AzureRmVmssExtension `
-VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss `
-Name "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
-Publisher "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
-Type "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
-TypeHandlerVersion 1.0 `
-AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true `
-Setting $PublicSettings `
-ProtectedSetting $ProtectedSettings

# Update the scale set and apply the Custom Script Extension to the VM instances
Update-AzureRmVmss `
-ResourceGroupName $vmss.ResourceGroupName `
-Name $vmss.Name `
-VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

# Only needed for manual update VMSS – warning tells them all to update, so modify to suit
$jobs=@()
Get-AzureRmVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $vmss.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $vmss.Name | foreach {
$jobs+=Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $vmss.ResourceGroupName -Name $vmss.Name -InstanceId $_.InstanceId -AsJob
}

$jobs | Wait-Job
$jobs | Receive-Job
```

Kudos to the author https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Tim+Omta